# With the stack and heap parts of memory, which one is managed by the .NET garbage collector?

Tags: c#

With the stack and heap parts of memory, which one is managed by the .NET garbage collector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory on the heap is managed by the garbage collector. Memory on the stack is deterministic and is returned to the pool when it goes out of scope.

Comment: "destroyed" is perhaps a bit strong. Ignored, maybe. But unless the thread terminates, it mainly just sits there.

Comment: @Marc, I couldn't figure out a good way to put it. Do you agree with my change?

Comment: It depends what you mean by scope... Stack space can (optionally) be cleared when *entering* a method, but IIRC it dies nothing when exiting. So that just leaves stack-teardown at thread-termination.

Comment: There is no 'stack pool', nothing is getting returned nor destroyed.  It is just a 1 megabyte array with an index, the stack pointer.

Comment: What is stored on the stack when a Reference Type is created on the heap?

Comment: @Kombucha - maybe a reference (roughly speaking, the address) - but maybe not even that. Well, stricty speaking the reference is on the head of stack briefly, but the is typically (one of) discarded (popped), stored in a local, or stored in a field (static or instance).

Comment: @Marc you are probably right, stores a reference to the value's memory address?  maybe.  Anyone?

Comment: @Kombucha - (I added more detail), but that isn't the job of the stack.

Comment: So when code is executed in memory, what part of the memory is the following code stored on?  int myInt = 5;  =Is it on STACK?

Comment: @Kombucha the value of the Value Type i is stored on the stack.

Comment: @Kombucha - is that in a method, or is that a field initializer ;p (it matters). Also, the compiler may remove it if not used, so the answer could be "nowhere".

Answer (score 3):

Just the (managed) heap. The stack may have *references* to objects, but not the objects themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the level of abstraction you're considering.  At a managed level, there is a single 'managed heap', but it is actually broken into separate buffers to support generational garbage collection.  There is also an unmanaged heap, from which unmanaged code can allocate memory in blissful ignorance of the CLR.  All of this is implemented with one underlying OS process memory space where all of the various heaps live.

The story is complicated by the fact that the GC can compact its various heaps as part of collection.  When this happens, the GC moves memory around, which means pointers can be invalidated.  In order to accomodate this, the GC reserves the right to modify references throughout the application to point to the correct location.  In this sense, the GC manages the 'stack', too, since the references stored on the stack can change to where they are pointing.